# Inserting at the end of a line in VIM

Tags: vim

So for a long time I've had a bad habit of going to the end of a line, hitting the <kbd>i</kbd> key and then hitting the right arrow to insert after that last character. However, this is extremely inefficient and impossible to do with <kbd>h</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>l</kbd>.

What's a better way to insert at the VERY end of the line?

Answer (score 242, accepted):

Use <kbd>A</kbd> command instead of <kbd>i</kbd>. The command appends text at the end of the line. See `:help A`.

---

In normal mode press <kbd>A</kbd> (uppercase). Vim will be switched to insert mode, and the cursor will be moved to the end of the current line ready for input.

Comment: IMO, this should be the accepted answer. One keystroke - clear winner.

Comment: not only is this the right answer, using A develops one's habit to use other  uppercase commands (e.g: I vs. i; O vs. o, D vs d; and C); in addition, it also makes ones appreciate the logic of :map Y y$

Comment: Also helpful to note that the `a` (lowercase) command inserts after the current character and `I` (Uppercase) inserts at the beginning of the line

Answer (score 31):

The <kbd>$</kbd> positions you at the end of line.

Then, to enter *insert* mode AFTER the end of line, press <kbd>a</kbd>.

So, simply typing <kbd>$</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> while in command mode will do what you are asking.

Comment: The answer below this is the correct answer. `A` moves the cursor to the end of the line and switches into insert mode.

Comment: I mean, it's still correct. There's one more character, but still a perfectly valid solution, especially if you're i.e. already at the end of the line

Comment: even though `a` in and of itself isn't what the question asked for (and I'm not saying this question claims as such), I never knew `a` existed and that's a pretty cool command for the back pocket. One keystroke definitely embraces the spirit of vim more, but I only knew about `i` (insert at cursor). I'd never know about `a` (insert after cursor) otherwise, thanks for posting, sir! (And agree with @Zoe it's a bit far-fetched to call it incorrect)