# How to add new line in bashrc file in ubuntu?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, vim

I'm trying to update my bashrc file in ubuntu with some environment variables.

I can do this using below command.

```
echo 'export APP=/opt/tinyos-2.x/apps' >> ~/.bashrc
```

But I want to do it manually, meaning open the file with vim editor then add it.
The problem here is when I open the bashrc file the end line is "fi" and when I reach there and press insert and then enter to go to new line it stays at the same line and moves the fi word only or create A or C or B random characters.

May I know please some commands to handle this bashrc file so that I could add a new line and then my variables over there?

I've tried to look online but didn't find what am looking for.

Comment: how are you opening the bashrc file?

Comment: @VaibhavDhoke, vi ~/.bashrc

Comment: Thought so, open it with gedit & edit it.

Comment: @VaibhavDhoke, that can be done..but am more interested in commands ...! How can I do that using commands...?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41657784/inserting-at-the-end-of-a-line-in-vim

Comment: `$ nano ~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 9):

Since you didn't specify if you have terminal access only or also GUI.
If you have terminal access only, any editor would do it.
Popular editors like [nano](https://www.nano-editor.org/) or [vim](http://www.vim.org) come installed by default in most Ubuntu releases.

To use nano, in your terminal, type
`nano ~/.bashrc`

Then press Ctrl + w +v to go to the end, add what you want to add, the Ctrl + o to save changes, Ctrl +x to exit.
You will need to log out and log back on, or run `source ~/.profile` to make your changes available to your bash environment.

Answer (score 6):

Here's what you can do in vim.

1. Press the letter `G`. It will take you to the last line.
2. Press the letter `O`. It will allow you to insert text after the current lne.
3. Type in your content - `export APP=/opt/tinyos-2.x/apps`
4. Press the `ESC` key get out of editing mode.
5. Press the key `:`. It will allow you type commands.
6. Type `wq` followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This will save the file and quit vim.

You are done.

Comment: One should start with how to enter the bashrc using vim. That would complete the answer. vim ~/.bashrc

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `Vim`/`Vi` editor you need to use i/insert key to start editing, then for saving use escape & then wq to save and exit. For More detailed instructions please visit this [link](https://www.radford.edu/~mhtay/CPSC120/VIM_Editor_Commands.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, learning vim in a week (or even in a day) is tough. Took me more than a month to actually be productive on it as mh daily editor. But just to tell you. Go to the line after which you want to ass a new line using `H-J-K-L` or arrow keys. Then presss `o`. It'll spawn a new line below it and go into insert mode as well. Then write and press `Esc`. Enter `:wq`.